# Trying to find equivalent of an inner join with variable length relationships and cpyher

Tags: neo4j, cypher

In my db I have resources tagged with tags. The tags can be within other tags (i.e. 'neo4j' would be connected to 'databases' like this: `(neo4j:tag)-[:WITHIN]->(databases:tag)` ), though not all tags have parents. Resources are returned if they're directly or indirectly (via children) connected to resources with a query like this:

```
MATCH (re:resource)-[:TAGGED_WITH]->(:tag)-[:WITHIN_TAG*0..3]->(parent:tag)
WHERE u.uid IN {includedTags}
RETURN DISTINCT re;
```

This issue with this is if a user searches for multiple tags (i.e. 'neo4j' and 'databases') resources are returned if they match any search tag. What I want is to have only resources that match all returned. This would allow the search to narrow as more tags were searched rather than expand.

Before using a variable length path (only returning resources directly tagged with all search tags) I achieved this by keeping track of the count of connected tags:

```
WITH DISTINCT re, count(*) AS connected 
WHERE connected = SIZE({includedSets})
```

I can't quite figure out how to do something similar here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the [`all` predicate function](https://neo4j.com/docs/developer-manual/current/cypher/functions/predicate/#functions-all):

```
MATCH (re:resource)-[:TAGGED_WITH]->(:tag)-[:WITHIN_TAG*0..3]->(parent:tag)
WITH re, collect(parent) AS parentTags
WHERE all(tag IN {includedTags} WHERE tag IN parentTags)
RETURN re;
```

Performance-wise, this might not be the best solution, but first, let's see if it works.

If you pass check for uids, collect those properties of the parent:

```
MATCH (re:resource)-[:TAGGED_WITH]->(:tag)-[:WITHIN_TAG*0..3]->(parent:tag)
WITH re, collect(parent.uid) AS parentTags
WHERE all(tag IN {includedTags} WHERE tag IN parentTags)
RETURN re;
```

If a resource has many tags, this optimization might help:

```
WITH {includedTags} as includedTags
UNWIND includedTags as tagId
MATCH (re:resource)-[:TAGGED_WITH]->(:tag)-[:WITHIN_TAG*0..3]->(parent:tag {uid: tagId})
WITH re, includedTags, count(parent) AS parentTags
WHERE size(includedTags) = parentTags
RETURN re;
```

Comment: Great! This works as expected. I'm matching based on a uid property (includedTags is an array of string uids), which I think would be faster than matching on a whole node? If you have thoughts on enhancing performance I'd love to hear them. The query is live at knowlo.io if you're interested.

Comment: I added an optimized version - but whether this speeds up things really depends on your data set, so you should do some simple benchmarking to see how well it works.